# Генерация страниц

Tags: javascript, html, php, css, mysql

Может у кого есть идеи как реализовать такое:
Например подан в БД запрос создать страницу, в БД создается запись (например: id=1 title=home). Возможно ли к данной записи прикрутить определенный HTML документ, что то вроде шаблона.

Comment: Учитвая ваш подход к реализации, то проще всего для вас будет добавить в бд поле `template`

----------------------------------------

`$template = file_get_contents($row['template'] . ".html");`

----------------------------------------

И дальше пляски с: strpreg_replace, preg_replace и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно создать **ОДНУ** страницу с GET-обработчиком, которому в свою очередь подавать данные для построения индивидуальной страницы( на основе ID, например ).

Comment: Как сделать этот GET-обработчик ???